# EPPlus Excel File. Show correct output for diagonal cell

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Using [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) I wrote code to show diagonal cell information.

I read this [tutorial on how to achieve this in Excel](http://newexceltips.blogspot.nl/2012/12/how-to-split-cell-diagonally.html#.WFJia30bi98).

This is the code I wrote:

```
private void AddDiagonalTitleHeaders(ExcelWorksheet ws, string diagonalLocation)
{
    var diagonalCell = ws.Cells[diagonalLocation];
    var border = diagonalCell.Style.Border;
    border.Diagonal.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
    border.DiagonalDown = true;

    diagonalCell.Style.Font.Size = 18;
    diagonalCell.Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Top;

    var altEnter = ((char)10).ToString();
    var spaces = " ";
    var diagonalText = string.Format("{1}{1}{1}ActionFlags{0}{0}{0}{0}{0}{0}{0}{0}Status", altEnter, spaces);
    diagonalCell.Value = diagonalText;
}
```

When I open the Excel file it initially looks like this:

[image: Incorrect view.]

Then I double click the cell to enter mode: 'editing directly in cells'.
I click away and then I see the correct output result:

[image: Correct output.]

**My question:** What can I do to immediately show the correct output result?

FYI:

```
var diagonalText = "   ActionFlags\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nStatus"; //Is the same
```

Comment: You could just use `\n` instead of altEnter. Or write `var altEnter = "\n";` although String.Format works with chars too

Comment: I already changed that before you wrote this :-) Still does not change the outcome. It works exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning on text wrapping:

```
diagonalCell.Style.WrapText = true;
```

Comment: Ernie you are the uncrowned king of EPPlus! Once again you are spot on!